# correlations from R in texshop

Tags: texshop

I have this code that I got from R to look into correlations. Now im trying to get the output in a pdf file trough texshop but i keep getting errors.

this is the code:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rlllllllllllllllll}
  \hline
 & ETR & cetr & mpbt & resid & PowerDistance & Individualism & Masculinity & Uncertainty avoidance & return on assets & leverage & Intangible assets & size & nol & Foreign income & Equity income in earnings & fyear & sic \\ 
  \hline
ETR &  1.000  &  0.363*** & -0.011  & -0.011  &  0.105*** & -0.046*** & -0.019**  & -0.003  & -0.055*** &  0.012  &  0.030*** & -0.061**  &  0.143*** &  0.465*** &  0.030*** &  0.062*** & -0.128*** \\ 
  cetr &  0.384*** &  1.000  &  0.359*** &  0.358*** &  0.085*** & -0.035*** & -0.005  &  0.008  &  0.040*** &  0.012  &  0.004  & -0.063**  &  0.090*** &  0.210*** &  0.004  &  0.078*** &  0.064*** \\ 
  mpbt & -0.003  &  0.001  &  1.000  &  0.981*** & -0.011  & -0.018**  & -0.032*** &  0.016*  &  0.119*** &  0.018**  &  0.015*  &  0.039  & -0.042*** & -0.269*** & -0.088*** &  0.118*** &  0.008  \\ 
  resid &  0.044*** &  0.005  &  0.000  &  1.000  & -0.015*  & -0.013  & -0.024*** &  0.015*  &  0.100*** &  0.020**  &  0.000  &  0.042*  & -0.044*** & -0.283*** & -0.092*** &  0.116*** &  0.013  \\ 
  PowerDistance &  0.057*** &  0.063*** & -0.005  & -0.005  &  1.000  & -0.167*** & -0.025*** &  0.149*** & -0.017*  &  0.015*  &  0.018**  &  0.124*** & -0.007  &  0.075*** &  0.006  &  0.018**  &  0.044*** \\ 
  Individualism & -0.056*** & -0.057*** & -0.004  &  0.001  & -0.799*** &  1.000  &  0.845*** & -0.781*** &  0.022*** &  0.053*** &  0.004  & -0.095*** & -0.003  & -0.038*** &  0.057*** & -0.073*** &  0.003  \\ 
  Masculinity & -0.040*** & -0.013  & -0.025*** & -0.003  & -0.407*** &  0.547*** &  1.000  & -0.584*** & -0.023*** &  0.024*** &  0.010  & -0.078*** & -0.001  & -0.027*** &  0.032*** & -0.053*** & -0.025*** \\ 
  Uncertainty avoidance & -0.014*  &  0.008  &  0.002  & -0.003  &  0.480*** & -0.402*** & -0.431*** &  1.000  & -0.020**  &  0.010  &  0.017*  &  0.101*** &  0.015*  &  0.018**  & -0.038*** &  0.055*** & -0.004  \\ 
  return on assets &  0.032*** &  0.158*** & -0.011  & -0.028*** & -0.023*** &  0.000  &  0.013*  & -0.045*** &  1.000  & -0.156*** & -0.079*** &  0.315*** & -0.250*** &  0.318*** &  0.014*  & -0.078*** & -0.026*** \\ 
  leverage &  0.012  &  0.008  &  0.000  & -0.002  &  0.004  & -0.009  & -0.015*  & -0.004  &  0.038*** &  1.000  &  0.205*** &  0.107*** &  0.141*** & -0.054*** &  0.142*** &  0.032*** & -0.207*** \\ 
  Intangible assets & -0.007  & -0.010  & -0.012  &  0.009  &  0.008  &  0.004  & -0.079*** &  0.036*** & -0.121*** &  0.002  &  1.000  &  0.023  &  0.158*** & -0.044*** &  0.043*** &  0.046*** &  0.047*** \\ 
  size &  0.023  &  0.040  &  0.081*** &  0.087*** &  0.156*** & -0.142*** & -0.071*** &  0.110*** &  0.319*** &  0.101*** &  0.181*** &  1.000  &  0.117*** &  0.203*** &  0.247*** & -0.029  & -0.136*** \\ 
  nol &  0.077*** &  0.033*** & -0.009  &  0.013*  & -0.021**  &  0.033*** & -0.041*** &  0.047*** & -0.274*** & -0.069*** &  0.147*** & -0.008  &  1.000  &  0.141*** &  0.039*** &  0.093*** & -0.075*** \\ 
  Foreign income &  0.019**  &  0.007  &  0.000  &  0.001  &  0.038*** &  0.004  &  0.136*** &  0.014*  & -0.008  &  0.002  & -0.055*** &  0.176*** & -0.014*  &  1.000  &  0.091*** & -0.059*** & -0.148*** \\ 
  Equity income in earnings & -0.025*** & -0.011  &  0.000  &  0.000  &  0.001  & -0.006  & -0.003  &  0.006  &  0.024*** &  0.001  &  0.030*** &  0.064**  & -0.024*** &  0.000  &  1.000  & -0.099*** & -0.132*** \\ 
  fyear &  0.047*** &  0.051*** & -0.028*** & -0.009  &  0.060*** & -0.061*** & -0.058*** &  0.058*** & -0.073*** &  0.024*** &  0.066*** &  0.049*  &  0.093*** &  0.012  & -0.014*  &  1.000  &  0.072*** \\ 
  sic & -0.051*** &  0.070*** & -0.024*** & -0.012  &  0.051*** & -0.041*** & -0.034*** &  0.024*** & -0.034*** &  0.006  &  0.140*** & -0.028  & -0.019**  & -0.035*** & -0.023*** &  0.081*** &  1.000  \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Except for the fact that the table is far too wide, your code works fine here.

Comment: the error i get is l.2 \begin{table}[ht]

Comment: Please give the full, compilable, code you are trying to use? Do you actually have a \begin{document}? Also, that table is very wide so won't fit in the width of a normal page.

Answer (score 1):

Your table has 18 [!] columns. In order to typeset it on a single page, it's advisable to (i) switch to landscape mode, (ii) reduce the font size, (iii) reduce the amount of intercolumn whitespace, (iv) allow linebreaking (with hyphenation) in some of the header cells, and (v) abbreviate some of the header cells.

While it's *possible* to typeset the table using these adjustments, it doesn't mean it's *advisable* to do so. Might your readers be better off if you just mention a few key correlations?

Incidentally, if the table you've posted is a correlation matrix, why isn't it symmetric? Just curious.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' env.
\usepackage{dcolumn}  % for 'D' column type
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env.
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\Centering' macro (allows hyphenation)
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\toprule', '\midrule', and '\bottomrule' macros
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}  % align number on decimal marker
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcommand\mC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{C}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\newcommand\sym[1]{^{#1}}
\hyphenation{power-dis-tance}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\scriptsize % 30% linear reduction in font size
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{17}{d{2.5}} @{}}
\toprule
& \mC{ETR} & \mC{cetr} & \mC{mpbt} & \mC{resid} & \mC{PowerDistance} & \mC{Individualism} & \mC{Masculinity} & \mC{Uncertainty avoidance} & \mC{return on assets} & \mC{leverage} & \mC{Intangible assets} & \mC{size} & \mC{nol} & \mC{Foreign income} & \mC{Eq.\ inc.\ in earn.} & \mC{fyear} & \mC{sic} \\ 
\midrule
ETR &  1  &  0.363\sym{***} & -0.011  & -0.011  &  0.105\sym{***} & -0.046\sym{***} & -0.019\sym{**}  & -0.003  & -0.055\sym{***} &  0.012  &  0.030\sym{***} & -0.061\sym{**}  &  0.143\sym{***} &  0.465\sym{***} &  0.030\sym{***} &  0.062\sym{***} & -0.128\sym{***} \\ 
  cetr &  0.384\sym{***} &  1  &  0.359\sym{***} &  0.358\sym{***} &  0.085\sym{***} & -0.035\sym{***} & -0.005  &  0.008  &  0.040\sym{***} &  0.012  &  0.004  & -0.063\sym{**}  &  0.090\sym{***} &  0.210\sym{***} &  0.004  &  0.078\sym{***} &  0.064\sym{***} \\ 
  mpbt & -0.003  &  0.001  &  1  &  0.981\sym{***} & -0.011  & -0.018\sym{**}  & -0.032\sym{***} &  0.016\sym{*}  &  0.119\sym{***} &  0.018\sym{**}  &  0.015\sym{*}  &  0.039  & -0.042\sym{***} & -0.269\sym{***} & -0.088\sym{***} &  0.118\sym{***} &  0.008  \\ 
  resid &  0.044\sym{***} &  0.005  &  0.000  &  1  & -0.015\sym{*}  & -0.013  & -0.024\sym{***} &  0.015\sym{*}  &  0.100\sym{***} &  0.020\sym{**}  &  0.000  &  0.042\sym{*}  & -0.044\sym{***} & -0.283\sym{***} & -0.092\sym{***} &  0.116\sym{***} &  0.013  \\ 
  PowerDistance &  0.057\sym{***} &  0.063\sym{***} & -0.005  & -0.005  &  1  & -0.167\sym{***} & -0.025\sym{***} &  0.149\sym{***} & -0.017\sym{*}  &  0.015\sym{*}  &  0.018\sym{**}  &  0.124\sym{***} & -0.007  &  0.075\sym{***} &  0.006  &  0.018\sym{**}  &  0.044\sym{***} \\ 
  Individualism & -0.056\sym{***} & -0.057\sym{***} & -0.004  &  0.001  & -0.799\sym{***} &  1  &  0.845\sym{***} & -0.781\sym{***} &  0.022\sym{***} &  0.053\sym{***} &  0.004  & -0.095\sym{***} & -0.003  & -0.038\sym{***} &  0.057\sym{***} & -0.073\sym{***} &  0.003  \\ 
  Masculinity & -0.040\sym{***} & -0.013  & -0.025\sym{***} & -0.003  & -0.407\sym{***} &  0.547\sym{***} &  1  & -0.584\sym{***} & -0.023\sym{***} &  0.024\sym{***} &  0.010  & -0.078\sym{***} & -0.001  & -0.027\sym{***} &  0.032\sym{***} & -0.053\sym{***} & -0.025\sym{***} \\ 
  Uncert.\ avoid. & -0.014\sym{*}  &  0.008  &  0.002  & -0.003  &  0.480\sym{***} & -0.402\sym{***} & -0.431\sym{***} &  1  & -0.020\sym{**}  &  0.010  &  0.017\sym{*}  &  0.101\sym{***} &  0.015\sym{*}  &  0.018\sym{**}  & -0.038\sym{***} &  0.055\sym{***} & -0.004  \\ 
  return on assets &  0.032\sym{***} &  0.158\sym{***} & -0.011  & -0.028\sym{***} & -0.023\sym{***} &  0.000  &  0.013\sym{*}  & -0.045\sym{***} &  1  & -0.156\sym{***} & -0.079\sym{***} &  0.315\sym{***} & -0.250\sym{***} &  0.318\sym{***} &  0.014\sym{*}  & -0.078\sym{***} & -0.026\sym{***} \\ 
  leverage &  0.012  &  0.008  &  0.000  & -0.002  &  0.004  & -0.009  & -0.015\sym{*}  & -0.004  &  0.038\sym{***} &  1  &  0.205\sym{***} &  0.107\sym{***} &  0.141\sym{***} & -0.054\sym{***} &  0.142\sym{***} &  0.032\sym{***} & -0.207\sym{***} \\ 
  Intangible assets & -0.007  & -0.010  & -0.012  &  0.009  &  0.008  &  0.004  & -0.079\sym{***} &  0.036\sym{***} & -0.121\sym{***} &  0.002  &  1  &  0.023  &  0.158\sym{***} & -0.044\sym{***} &  0.043\sym{***} &  0.046\sym{***} &  0.047\sym{***} \\ 
  size &  0.023  &  0.040  &  0.081\sym{***} &  0.087\sym{***} &  0.156\sym{***} & -0.142\sym{***} & -0.071\sym{***} &  0.110\sym{***} &  0.319\sym{***} &  0.101\sym{***} &  0.181\sym{***} &  1  &  0.117\sym{***} &  0.203\sym{***} &  0.247\sym{***} & -0.029  & -0.136\sym{***} \\ 
  nol &  0.077\sym{***} &  0.033\sym{***} & -0.009  &  0.013\sym{*}  & -0.021\sym{**}  &  0.033\sym{***} & -0.041\sym{***} &  0.047\sym{***} & -0.274\sym{***} & -0.069\sym{***} &  0.147\sym{***} & -0.008  &  1  &  0.141\sym{***} &  0.039\sym{***} &  0.093\sym{***} & -0.075\sym{***} \\ 
  Foreign income &  0.019\sym{**}  &  0.007  &  0.000  &  0.001  &  0.038\sym{***} &  0.004  &  0.136\sym{***} &  0.014\sym{*}  & -0.008  &  0.002  & -0.055\sym{***} &  0.176\sym{***} & -0.014\sym{*}  &  1  &  0.091\sym{***} & -0.059\sym{***} & -0.148\sym{***} \\ 
  Eq.\ inc.\ in earn. & -0.025\sym{***} & -0.011  &  0.000  &  0.000  &  0.001  & -0.006  & -0.003  &  0.006  &  0.024\sym{***} &  0.001  &  0.030\sym{***} &  0.064\sym{**}  & -0.024\sym{***} &  0.000  &  1  & -0.099\sym{***} & -0.132\sym{***} \\ 
  fyear &  0.047\sym{***} &  0.051\sym{***} & -0.028\sym{***} & -0.009  &  0.060\sym{***} & -0.061\sym{***} & -0.058\sym{***} &  0.058\sym{***} & -0.073\sym{***} &  0.024\sym{***} &  0.066\sym{***} &  0.049\sym{*}  &  0.093\sym{***} &  0.012  & -0.014\sym{*}  &  1  &  0.072\sym{***} \\ 
  sic & -0.051\sym{***} &  0.070\sym{***} & -0.024\sym{***} & -0.012  &  0.051\sym{***} & -0.041\sym{***} & -0.034\sym{***} &  0.024\sym{***} & -0.034\sym{***} &  0.006  &  0.140\sym{***} & -0.028  & -0.019\sym{**}  & -0.035\sym{***} & -0.023\sym{***} &  0.081\sym{***} &  1 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```